# Atom's add-selection-above keybinding only works with mouse clicks, not up/down arrows

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

I'm new to this site and pretty new to programming. I just got a new laptop, and I immediately installed Atom on it to edit HTML and Java. For some reason, the <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> key that I was familiar with doesn't add the above (or below) lines as selection...I've already disabled the windows screen orientation shortcut that conflicts, and when I <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd> + Click I can still add to selection, but it's very annoying with a trackpad and when the item is directly above, where using up arrow would be much easier.

I also attempted to create an alternate shortcut, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> but I had no idea how to name it:

```
'alternate-select-up':
  'shift-alt-up': 'editor:add-selection-above'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Atom on Windows, the default keybinding for adding selection above is Alt+Ctrl+Up and for adding selection below is Alt+Ctrl+Down.

If that is not working and you prefer to use Alt+Shift+Up for adding selection above and Alt+Shift+Down for adding selection below you can add the following lines to your keymap.cson file:

```
'atom-text-editor':
    'alt-shift-up': 'editor:add-selection-above'
    'alt-shift-down': 'editor:add-selection-below'
```

You can open the keymap.cson file on File->Open Your Keymap.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's conflicting with native shortcut. Here's a workaround that was ok for me, add in `~/.atom/keymap.cson`:

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'alt-shift-k': 'editor:move-line-up'
  'alt-shift-j': 'editor:move-line-down'
  'ctrl-shift-up': 'editor:add-selection-above'
  'ctrl-shift-down': 'editor:add-selection-below'
```